# Refresh graph hosting view

Tags: objective-c, xcode, graph, core-plot

I've got a problem for 2 days now, still not able to solve it.
What I'm actually doing is trying to refresh a Graph Hosting View. When I open the UIViewController with the Graph Hosting View, a standard graph is automatically drawn. What I want is the graph being changed according to some coefficients the user can enter through a text field.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{   
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
float x = -10;
float a = [coeff1.text floatValue];
 NSMutableArray *data = [NSMutableArray array];
for (x; x <= 10; x=x+0.2)
{
    [data addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(x , a*x+1)]];
}
self.scatterPlot = [[TUTSimpleScatterPlot alloc] initWithHostingView:_graphHostingView     andData:data];
[self.scatterPlot initialisePlot];
```

You probably see that all i want is the view to be refreshed when the user enters a new value for "coeff1.text" 
Excuse me for this question probably being silly, but I honestly don't see any way around it and I have tried a lot of things and am still not able to refresh the graph. What I thought to be possible in some way is to update the graph by entering the new coefficient and clicking on a button (IBAction)...

Thank you in advance,
Eric

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you're parsing a float value incorrectly. This is how you do it:

```
  NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [NSNumberFormatter new];
  [formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
  NSNumber * myNumber = [formatter numberFromString:coeff1.text];
```

Next given that `coeff1` is actually an UITextField, you should be able to just register for its editing changed updates like this

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  [coeff1 addTarget:self action:@selector(editingChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
}

- (void)editingChanged:(UITextField *)textField {
  NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [NSNumberFormatter new];
  [formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
  NSNumber * myNumber = [formatter numberFromString:coeff1.text];
  NSMutableArray *data = [NSMutableArray array];
  for (x = 0; x <= 10; x=x+0.2)
  {
    [data addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(x , myNumber.floatValue*x+1)]];
  }
  self.scatterPlot = [[TUTSimpleScatterPlot alloc] initWithHostingView:_graphHostingView     andData:data];
  [self.scatterPlot initialisePlot];

}
```